# in what document of RUP should i put the Use case attributes (form fields)?

Tags: rup, srs

In what document of RUP should I put the Use case attributes (form fields)?

Suppose that there is a registration use case for some system. As a system analyst writing SRS, where could I write the specific attribute (form fields) of the registration use case? what is the name of this document?

Comment: what do you mean by use case attribute?

Comment: use case attributes are the data model

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and put that inside the same SRS.